# Waiting on async tasks in Ansible throws error: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_job_id'

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, ansible

I'm spawning off several async tasks in Ansible and attempting to wait for them to all finish before I proceed on the the next set of tasks (9 total). Here's an example of a couple of them:

```yaml
- name: EC2 spin up
  async: 6000
  poll: 0
  shell: # spin up an instance with a playbook
  register: ec2_item
  when: deployment_type == 'x' or deployment_type == 'y'

- name: EC2 spin up another
  async: 6000
  poll: 0
  shell: # # spin up another instance with a playbook
  register: ec2_item_again
  when: deployment_type == 'x' or deployment_type == 'y'
```

After this, I'm running this block to wait on them:

```yaml
- name: Wait on EC2 Async Tasks
  async_status:
  jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ec2_item }}"
    - "{{ ec2_item_again }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 60
  delay: 15
```

Eventually, things finishing, but it errors out without he following:

```json
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_job_id'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/app-root/src/playbooks/sb_build_flow.yml': line 201, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      delay: 6\n    - async_status:\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

It's trying to look at a task that no longer exists, but I'm unsure how to actually get this work. Again, I'm just trying to get Ansible too wait for the async tasks to finish before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`async_status` module – Obtain status of asynchronous task -Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/async_status_module.html#examples) there is at least an incorrect idention at `jid`.

The following minimal example seems to be running successful

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Wait ONE
    shell:
      cmd: "sleep 15"
    async: 6000
    poll: 0
    register: ONE

  - name: Wait TWO
    shell:
      cmd: "sleep 15"
    async: 6000
    poll: 0
    register: TWO

  - name: Wait on tasks
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    loop: "[{{ ONE }}, {{ TWO }}]"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: job_result
    until: job_result.finished
    retries: 60
    delay: 15
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Wait ONE] *****************************************
changed: [test.example.com]

TASK [Wait TWO] *****************************************
changed: [test.example.com]
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait on tasks (60 retries left).

TASK [Wait on tasks] ************************************
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=229736317985.176035)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=829194009194.176257)
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)